# Azure Exception - Blob Storage

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-eventhub

I am getting the below error message in log files. There are Azure configurations for the event hubs.

```
Error occurred in partition processor for partition NONE, com.azure.storage.blob.models.BlobStorageException: Status code 404, 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Error>
   <Code>ContainerNotFound</Code>
   <Message>The specified container does not exist.
```

Any idea on this?

Comment: I would recommend checking the Event Hub configuration and ensure that the blob container mentioned there exists in the storage account.

Comment: Thanks Gaurav. The blob container doesn't exist in the storage account . I manually created the container. The question here is , Azure will not create the container if it doesn't exist already?

Answer (score 1):

Kindly check the storage account for the existing configurations. Check whether the container is created or not. If not create the container and re-execute. Automatic container creation is not possible.